# How do I initialize list item in a method from a different class?

Tags: c#, oop, methods

I am trying to find an id or string within a `List` returned from a method in a different class. The solution below does not work. I have initialized the class, then called the method, and am trying to get the id.

```
public class RiskService
{
    private readonly Resource _matt = new Resource { Id = 1, Name = "Matt Sharpe" };
    private readonly Resource _john = new Resource { Id = 2, Name = "John Hillhouse" };
    private readonly Resource _julian = new Resource { Id = 3, Name = "Julian Jelfs" };
    private readonly Resource _darren = new Resource { Id = 4, Name = "Darren Thorpe" };
    private readonly Resource _jonm = new Resource { Id = 5, Name = "Jon Moore" };

    public List<Risk> GetRisks()
    {
        var risks = new List<Risk>();
        risks.Add(new Risk { Id = 1, Owner = _matt, RiskScore = 5, Status = RiskStatus.Approved, Title = "Lack Build Capacity In Dockyard" });
        risks.Add(new Risk { Id = 2, Owner = _john, RiskScore = 10, Status = RiskStatus.Unapproved, Title = "Small scale fire in warehouse" });
        risks.Add(new Risk { Id = 3, Owner = _matt, RiskScore = 17, Status = RiskStatus.Mitigated, Title = "Contract delays" });
        risks.Add(new Risk { Id = 4, Owner = _julian, RiskScore = 23, Status = RiskStatus.Open, Title = "Supplier insolvency" });
        risks.Add(new Risk { Id = 5, Owner = _darren, RiskScore = 13, Status = RiskStatus.Closed, Title = "Loss of key staff" });
        risks.Add(new Risk { Id = 6, Owner = _jonm, RiskScore = 97, Status = RiskStatus.Open, Title = "Fire in plant" });
        risks.Add(new Risk { Id = 7, Owner = _jonm, RiskScore = 97, Status = RiskStatus.Open, Title = "Fire in backup plant" });
        risks.Add(new Risk { Id = 8, Owner = _jonm, RiskScore = 45, Status = RiskStatus.Unapproved, Title = "Disaster recovery doesn't cover fire" });
        risks.Add(new Risk { Id = 9, Owner = _darren, RiskScore = 36, Status = RiskStatus.Approved, Title = "Component fails to meet performance" });
        risks.Add(new Risk { Id = 10, Owner = _john, RiskScore = 36, Status = RiskStatus.Approved, Title = "Component fails to meet performance" });
        return risks;
    }
}
```

To Find risks owned by Jon Moore, here is my Solution:

```
public class Solution
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RiskService riskService = new RiskService();
        Console.WriteLine(riskService.GetRisks().ElementAt(8));                              
    }       
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] with your question.  When you say "it does not work" that does not help us at all.  Be specific.

Comment: `riskService.Where(x=> x.Owner.Name =="xxx")`?

Comment: @DragandDrop pass the result of that LINQ to `Console.WriteLine()`, it won't be what you expect

Comment: Why are you passing a resource to owner?  Is owner supposed to be an owner or resource.

Comment: @maccettura, hard to see what you mean. I forgot the GetRisk? because it works. https://dotnetfiddle.net/4v1l1y. Hard to type on Dotfiddle when you don't have Vs and you are on a phone.

Comment: @DragandDrop your code on its own implies that the OP should fix this by doing: `Console.WriteLine(riskService.GetRisks().Where(x=> x.Owner.Name =="xxx"));` which would **not** work.  This is the dangers of just posting code in a comment with no context

Comment: I was adressing the comment in the code :"//Find risks owned by Jon Moore ". Check the fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/86IINQ. The result is correct. Perhaps I miss something.

Comment: I really think _his_ comment was his question.

Comment: Please always try to define **how** something is *"not working"*. Are you getting an exception? If so, what is it and which line is throwing it? Are you getting unexpected results? If so, what are they and what were you expecting them to be? Doing this will always help you get a better answer.

Comment: Your code is just grabbing the 9th element from the list (the element at index `8`). What do you *want* it to do?

Comment: @Waqz, May you confirm that the comment in your orginal post was what you were trying to achieve? https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49016289/1

Comment: The more I look, the more confusing it gets: 1/. Title seems irrevelant to the issue. 2/. Comment in the code that was remove by edit show an other intends. 3/. The code you show in your solution look like a place holder. Witch is not even an attempt.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RiskService riskService = new RiskService();
    var result = riskService.GetRisks().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 8);
    Console.WriteLine(result?.Owner.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To *find risks owned by Jon Moore*<sup>(1)</sup>, you can used [Linq Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx)
to filter your `List<Risk>`.
In the predicate navigate to the wanted property Risk > Owner > MyProperty.

```
var risks = new RiskService().GetRisks().Where(x=> x.Owner.Name=="Jon Moore");

foreach(var risk in risks){
    //  risk.Dump();
    Console.WriteLine("Id:"+risk.Id+" OwnerID:"+risk.Owner.Id+" OwnerName:"+risk.Owner.Name+" Title:"+risk.Title);
}
```

Here is a working exemple:[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MfQr3c)

---

<sub>[(1): From a comment in The original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49016289/1)</sub>